# Is there any shell command to get history of PHP updating operation?

Tags: php, shell, version, history

Does anyoune know if is there any ssh command to see the past changes to PHP version?
I mean, I know I can check the present installed version, but I would need to discover if it has been changed and when (a sort of history of PHP updating operation).
The server is GNU/Linux.
Thanks to anyone who will help with this.

Comment: Well, that depends on the distribution you are using, obviously, since those come with different software management systems.

Comment: In general you can "grep" such information from the system log files (or the separate log files the software management system writes). So no, there is no "command" as such, but you have the toolbox to create one. Be creative, grep through the files, work your way forward until you have exactly the output you want.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Unfortunately it didn't solve may issue because I didn't find any interesting result. I guess maybe PHP has been installed from graphic interface instead of from shell...

Comment: It is irrelevant whether php has been installed using a shell of a graphical interface. The point is that an installation is registered inside the software management system. Which logs its actions. That is where you will find traces of that. So: have you checked that? May I ask how?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea of how to do this. Moreover, I am not the admin of this server... :(

Comment: It would help if you could find out what distribution of Linux that system uses. Have a try with that: `cat /proc/version` .

Comment: The result was "Linux version 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (g cc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) )"

Comment: OK, you are looking at a RedHat based system, that means you are using an `rpm` based software management system. It has been many, many years since I last used one of those, so I am not really familiar with that any more. I think `rpm -qa --last` will give you a good starting point. You could extend that like this: `rpm -qa --last | grep -v php` for example. And I am sure you will find articles when you search for something like "redhat rpm package install history" or similar. There is no finished tool, you have to combine from the wealth of linux utilities.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution, I love it. The poit is that, if my understanding is correct, it allows only to discover the installation date of the current installed version of PHP. I couldn't discovr the history of installed versions... But thank you for your advise, I'll continue searchin in this direction.